# Is it possible to tour the facility where Kahlúa is made?

Tags: tours, mexico

Now I know you can visit plenty of wineries, breweries, and distilleries around the world. But my favourite alcoholic beverage is Kahlúa, a coffee liqueur from Mexico exported around the world.

Does anybody know if it's possible for any random person, or also only under some special circumstances if that's the case, to tour the place where they make Kahlúa?

The company site doesn't mention anything, in fact I can't even find where in Mexico it's distilled/manufactures/bottled other than on the label it just says its a product of Mexico.

Comment: I believe the distillery is in Mexico City... however, I have no information on tours.

Comment: Pretend you're a journalist.

Comment: @Ginamin: I had heard it was in Puebla but never managed to verify it.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: Will Stack Exchange issue me a press pass? (-:

Comment: Fake it till you make it. These days just saying you're a travel blogger can get you preferential treatment ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo: True. Just mentioning that I do some reviews on TripAdvisor seemed to get a hostel owner fawning over me. Or maybe that was mentioning that I've worked in a hostel for years. Most of the time I don't want special treatment but for Kahlúa I could make an exception (-:

Comment: I use old business cards from a previous journalism gig every now and then. :D

Comment: I just made my own...

Comment: It sounds like I am the only one here who hasn't been on a tour of the Kahlúa plant! (-;

Comment: Tequila tourism is big business in the city of Tequila, Jalisco (about an hour from Guadaljara).  I'd be surprised if you couldn't get a Kahlua tour as well... Mexico makes a lot of money off of tourism... and they aren't nearly as paranoid about safety--of their tourists, or of the products their tourists might contaminate--so there's less reason not to allow tours. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An e-mail to Kahlúa asking about tours was answered with:

> Thanks for your email and your interest in Kahlúa.
>
> Unfortunately we don't currently offer a tour of the Kahlúa facilities.
>
> If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to ask.
>
> Best regards
>
> Martin

Comment: That's the definitive way to check! (-:

Answer (score 6):

Contacting Aaron Vanek who wrote an article with examiner.com about a tour of the factory may give you a good start.

[On location with Kahlua coffee liqueur in Mexico (part VI - finale)](http://www.examiner.com/cocktails-in-los-angeles/on-location-with-kahlua-coffee-liqueur-mexico-part-vi-finale)